# Rails 4: Paperclip and rails_admin "undefined method `attachment_definitions' error"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, rails-admin

I am using rails_admin and paperclip but installing rails_admin with a model having paperclip attributes `has_attached_file` throws an error

```
undefined method `attachment_definitions'
```

I am using Rails 4 and rails_admin at master git branch and protected attributes gem.

Comment: also having this issue. please update if you've found an answer!

Comment: See https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1691

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am on rails 3 still but ran into the same issue. I am fairly certain its an issue with the latest paperclip and rails_admin. I backed paperclip down to paperclip (3.4.2) and everything works.

Another thing of note I am using ruby 1.9.3

So for the newer rails guys/galls

In your gem file

```
gem "paperclip", "3.4.2"
```

then `bundle update`

not sure if other versions will work but I know that one does

Comment: I've confirmed this fix also works for Rails 4.0.0 on Ruby 2.0.0-p195

Comment: Damn! Thank you very much Tyrel. I can't believe this doesn't work with the latest version of Paperclip

Answer (score 3):

Are you properly calling has_attached_file in the model itself?

I had ruby (1.9.3), Rails (4.0.1), paperclip (3.5.2) and rails_admin (0.5.0) working without error. Then I created a new model. It had all the usual paperclip columns and should have worked.  But I got that same error message.

**My problem** (duh) was that I neglected to configure paperclip in the model itself, but had the paperclip columns in my schema.  I wasn't calling has_attached_file ... in my model.

```
has_attached_file :img...
```

I loosely recall that rails_admin sniffs certain paperclip smelling columns and acts on it.  So I had the paperclip like columns, which rails_admin detected, but never called has_attaached_file resulting in the error.  And that error makes sense, there were indeed no "attachment_definitions" to speak of!

Comment: You saved one project to die. Thank you so much . It really helped. I found columns in the database for which rails_admin is looking for attachment defination on the model which is not there. `paperclip` and `rails_admin` are fine. There is a issue in db and model level.

Comment: I had a similar problem. In my case was because under the hood I was calling `attachment_definitions` before the `has_attached_file` method

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that `has_attached_file` declaration is missing in your model. However this is a bug in rails_admin (in paperclip factory). I submitted the pull request here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/pull/2410

Until then, you can use rails_admin from this branch: https://github.com/drap-hr/rails_admin/tree/v0.7.0-fixes (which is 0.7.0 version with paperclip factory fixed)