# Rails - NoMethodError in Devise::SessionsController when I log in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, devise

When I try to log in to the app, I got this error statement in browser:

```
undefined method `attachment_definitions' for #<Class:0x007f800e91e840>
```

and this in the terminal:

```
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"eriPHHi/FGBOFOpDidHQ0WGHeT6P6rx6OobOlI3yVVc=", "lsd"=>"AVpgheCi", "user"=>{"email"=>"email@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"", "timezone"=>"420", "lgnrnd"=>"174002_RDjg", "lgnjs"=>"1372034619", "locale"=>"en_US"}
  User Load (89.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'mail@gmail.com' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (86.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "last_sign_in_at" = '2013-07-23 14:33:24.674379', "current_sign_in_at" = '2013-07-24 14:31:20.626373', "sign_in_count" = 16, "updated_at" = '2013-07-24 14:31:20.633644' WHERE "users"."id" = 11
   (55.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 694ms

    NoMethodError (undefined method `attachment_definitions' for #<Class:0x007f800e91e840>):
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
  randumb (0.4.0) lib/randumb/relation.rb:164:in `method_missing'
  delayed_paperclip (2.6.0.0) lib/delayed_paperclip/attachment.rb:24:in `delayed_options'
  delayed_paperclip (2.6.0.0) lib/delayed_paperclip/attachment.rb:29:in `delay_processing?'
  delayed_paperclip (2.6.0.0) lib/delayed_paperclip/attachment.rb:69:in `block in save_with_prepare_enqueueing'
  delayed_paperclip (2.6.0.0) lib/delayed_paperclip/attachment.rb:68:in `tap'
  delayed_paperclip (2.6.0.0) lib/delayed_paperclip/attachment.rb:68:in `save_with_prepare_enqueueing'
  paperclip (3.5.0) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:75:in `block in add_active_record_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:416:in `_run__273581649550948589__save__1608755943708162097__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:264:in `create_or_update'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:84:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/validations.rb:50:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block (2 levels) in save'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:518:in `block in transaction_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:268:in `trace_execution_scoped'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:513:in `transaction_with_trace_ActiveRecord_self_name_transaction'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:259:in `block in save'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:270:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:258:in `save'
  devise (3.0.0) lib/devise/models/trackable.rb:30:in `update_tracked_fields!'
  devise (3.0.0) lib/devise/hooks/trackable.rb:7:in `block in <top (required)>'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:14:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:14:in `block in _run_callbacks'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:9:in `each'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/hooks.rb:9:in `_run_callbacks'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:53:in `_run_callbacks'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:179:in `set_user'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:323:in `_perform_authentication'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/proxy.rb:127:in `authenticate!'
  devise (3.0.0) app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb:15:in `create'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:469:in `_run__1416762379271609182__process_action__4449580587613085988__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:38:in `block in process_action'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:318:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/rails3/action_controller.rb:37:in `process_action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:42:in `call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
  journey (1.0.4) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:184:in `call!'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:164:in `call'
  omniauth (1.1.4) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:49:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:12:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:22:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:16:in `call'
  newrelic_rpm (3.6.5.130) lib/new_relic/rack/developer_mode.rb:28:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.9) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__911033713188350571__call__1608755943708162097__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.9) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.9) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.9) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.4.5) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/radek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/radek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/radek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (1.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/radek/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/actionpack-3.2.9/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (42.7ms)
```

I see something like this the first time, what's wrong with Devise? Where to start with debugging/to start to look for a bug?

Thanks a lot, I am solving this over 2 hours and still nothing...

Comment: Can you share the rest of the backtrace, at least down to a a source file of your app (as opposed to a gem)?

Comment: Sure Peter, just added it. Thanks

Comment: @user984621 do have any before_save, after_save, before_update or after_update callbacks in user model?

Comment: Sachin - no, I don't have there any callbacks.

Comment: This looks like an issue with Paperclip, not Devise. See this related StackOverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523849/rails-4-paperclip-and-rails-admin-undefined-method-attachment-definitions-er, and this Github issue: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1674. You might just need to change the version for the paperclip or delayed paperclip gems.

Comment: Really, setting up the version of Paperclip on `gem "paperclip", "3.4.2"` solved this issue.